# Mongoose agreggate with an .every() equivalent

Tags: mongoose, filter, aggregate

i'm lost in my aggregate filters.

I want to regroup a list of Visitor by their request._id and add filter to that.

In each visitor, there is a `units` array, and in each there is a `steps` array.

I'm searching an equivalent of a array.every() instead of $elemMatch, for find a `true` data in each step for one unit.

```
const aggregateFilters = { 'visitors.request.units': { $elemMatch: { label: unit, 'workflow.steps': { $elemMatch: { role, 'state.done': true } } } } }
```

If i search  a `state.done: false` value, it's ok, because even if the others are `true`, i want the result.

But how can if filter that if i want just the steps with every `state.done: true`, when the $elemMatch work as a .find()?

I don't know if i'm clear ^^

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can flip your approach to get your desired result. Instead of finding where all of the sub documents are true, you can find where *none* of the subdocuments are false

```
const aggregateFilters = { 'visitors.request.units': { $elemMatch: { label: unit, 'workflow.steps': {role, {$ne: ['state.done', false]}}}}}
```

I did not test the above code, it's an example of the way the approach might work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response, I already tried that, but it's work as a .find() too. If a state.done is true in the visitors array, it is returned...

I finally find how with that:

`const aggregateFilters = { 'visitors.request.units': { $not: { $elemMatch: { label: unit, 'workflow.steps': { $elemMatch: { role, 'state.done': false } } } } } }`